# Rewrite block that is extended by other blocks

Tags: blocks, adminhtml, overrides

For example `Mage_Tax_Block_Sales_Order_Tax`. This block is used on the site itself but within the admin area `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Totals_Tax` is used which extends from it.

Now I want to change a function of this block. To do that I wanted to rewrite it but this function will only work for the site then. The block for the admin area will still extend from the base block and not my rewrite. Do I have to rewrite both blocks (seems bad because of redundancy) or is there a more elegant way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the rewrite mechanism is a magento feature. So you can't change the behaviour of php (which would be extending from `Mage_Tax_Block_Sales_Order_Tax` in your case)

In your case, you would have to rewrite the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Totals_Tax` with your own block and best practice would be to extend your new block from the one you are rewriting (so `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Totals_Tax`)

Since this block extends the `Mage_Tax_Block_Sales_Order_Tax` you can also override functions of this block